# Replacing pattern with variable

Tags: sed

I have 3 lines of numbers stored in a variable `$new` and I need to use this to replace 3 lines from a file which I have used `grep` and stored in another variable `$old`. I'm trying `sed "s/$old/$new/g" input > output`. But I'm getting an error :

`sed: 1: "s/\(    28.47969107  0. ...": unterminated substitute pattern`

My input file looks like:

```
scale
 1.000
primitive lattice vectors
    28.47969107  0.00000000  0.00000000
   0.00000000 28.47969107  0.00000000
   0.00000000  0.00000000 28.47969107
grid dimensions
  100 100 100
```

My `$old` is the lines

`28.47969107  0.00000000  0.00000000
   0.00000000 28.47969107  0.00000000
   0.00000000  0.00000000 28.47969107`

`$new` has the same format as old, just different numbers.

Comment: `sed` might be the wrong tool for this.  Show samples of `input`, `old`, `new`, and your desired `output`.

Comment: My old and new have the same format such as below:
            28.8737008089        0.1964626186        0.0087346254
             0.1957460913       29.4858745413       -0.1425364811
             0.0094444937       -0.1406789200       28.4825428592

The input is a long text file.

Comment: That is not helpful.  To be helpful, show samples of `input`, `old`, `new`, and your desired `output`.

Comment: My input has:
<some lines of text>
    28.47969107  0.00000000  0.00000000
   0.00000000 28.47969107  0.00000000
   0.00000000  0.00000000 28.47969107
<more lines of text>
I need just the three lines to be replaced.

Comment: Ajax, don't put the information in comments.  Comments mangle the format. Put it in the question where you have full editing capability and make sure that it appears as it should.

Comment: For trivial cases you could do it via shell too: `orig=$(cat input); modified=${orig/$old/$new}; printf '%s\n' "$modified" > output`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -e "/$old/i$new" -e "/$old/{N;N;d}" input > output
```

where

- `$old` can be just `28.47969107` or ONE first line `28.47969107 0.00000000 0.00000000`
- `$new` SHOULD be in form `28.47969107 0.00000000 0.00000000\n0.00000000 28.47969107 0.00000000\n0.00000000 0.00000000 28.47969107`

Other way (if you have new GNU sed (version >4.2.1) with `-z` option) to escape `newline` inside the vaiables:

```
sed -z "s/$(printf "%b" "$old"|sed '$!s/$/\\/')/$(printf "%b" "$new"|sed 's/$/\\/')/" input > output
```

Or if you do substitution inside the script assign function

```
end_esc(){ printf "%b" "$@"|sed '$!s/$/\\/' ; }
sed -z "s/$(end_esc $old)/$(end_esc $new)/" input > output
```

Comment: I still get the same error: 
`sed: 1: "/    28.47969107  0.000 ...": unterminated regular expression`

Comment: `i`nsert needs continuing newlines to be backslash escaped - and you can't have newlines in the address. Probably $IFS takes care of that here, but that's only because `$old` should be quoted.

Comment: @mikeserv I have stated it in requirements to variables below script

Comment: How does it match the other two lines? And the `\n` escape is not portable in the rhs - it will do funny things depending on the `sed`. Oh - especially for `i`nsert - most `sed`s need literal newlines backslash escaped - and the `i`nserted content doesn't actually start until after the first backslash escaped newline. Even GNU `sed` requires at least one backslash following the `i`.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's define a sample string for `new`:

```
$ new=$'1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9'
```

Now, let's remove the three lines that follow `primitive lattice vectors` and replace them with `new`:

```
$ awk -v "new=$new" 'f==1{print new} f{f--;next} {print} /primitive/{f=3}' input
scale
 1.000
primitive lattice vectors
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
grid dimensions
  100 100 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e '$!N;$b' -e "/\n.*\n/!N;s/$old/$new/;t" -e P\;D
```

The above will work, but here's the catch: newlines in `$old` need to be represented as `\n` and newlines in `$new` should be preceded by a `\`backslash. The newlines in your values are what gave you trouble. For example, after expansion:

```
sed 's/24.0000000001
.000000000000
.0000000000/...'
```

...doesn't work. That is an *unterminated regular expression* - you see?

Instead:

```
old='num\nnum\nnum'
new='num\
num\
num'
```

...is what you need.

If, for whatever reason, you find it cumbersome to escape the vars yourself, then you can do something like:

```
(  set -f; IFS='
'; printf '%s\\n' / .* '/!N;s/'$old
   printf '%s\\\n' */$new"/;t$IFS#"
)| sed -e '$N;$b' -f - -e P\;D input > output
```

But that would depend on there being no blank lines in either variable, and it probably isn't any easier.

Answer (score -1):

`sed s/"$old"/"$new"/g` works for me